# Sub-query at select statement error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, subquery

```
DECLARE @colSelect TABLE(name VARCHAR(100));

insert into @colSelect values ('id')
insert into @colSelect values ('d')
insert into @colSelect values ('rpn')
insert into @colSelect values ('criticality')
insert into @colSelect values ('dateCreated')

DECLARE @tableName varchar(100), @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime

SET @tableName = 'tblFmeas'
SET @startDate  = '2016-04-05 00:00:00'
SET @endDate    = '2016-04-05 00:00:00'


DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'select ' + (select * from @colSelect) + ' from ' + @tableName + ' where dateCreated between ' + @startDate + ' and' + @endDate;

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Someone have a suggestion for this?

Cause in my app, the user choose the columns that he want to see in report and i need to pass them for my query.

Comment: you should type in your query instead of providing a screenshot

Comment: All the different ways to turn rows in a table to a comma-separated string: http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Converting%20row%20values%20in%20a%20table%20to%20a%20single%20concatenated%20string.aspx

Comment: Sorry @vkp my bad!

Comment: really thank you @Jamiec! Sureee cursors ;)

Comment: Here are a few suggestions.  Never use a sub-query in the select portion of a query.  If you plan on executing Dynamic SQL you want it inside a stored procedure.  While were discussing Dynamic SQL, enumerate your inputs to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Now I understand @EastOfJupiter. Thank you! I'm reading a good article about Dynamic SQL right now. The article: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score -1):

Here it returning multiple values since there is no join condition so that's the issue.

Probably "Select Top 1 name from @colselect " will work. But not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This will not convert a list of values into a single comma separated string which is what the OP is asking for.

Also, if you're not sure what the OP is trying to achieve, why bother throwing an answer out there?